# Do I have SQL Server 2012 installed correctly?

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2012

So, I've only worked with MySQL, but I now need to work with a machine that the sysadmin has declared will only run SQL Server.  He installed SQL Server 2012, but I'm not sure that I have all the pieces necessary to continue.

When I open the Configuration manager, under SQL Services, all I see is Integration Services:

[image]

Is this a complete installation? I can't figure out what to enter when trying to connect to the server from the Management Studio.

I don't have access to the installation media to install more pieces, but I would prefer to know more before approaching the sysadmin.

Comment: it seems like you have only installed the sql server Integration servies

Comment: This question would seem to be best posted in dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DBA must have selected from `Features Selection` window the `Database Engine` box to install the Sql Server itself as showing in the following picture 
[image]

When you are connecting to a sql server instance you have to have GUI Client side application installed on your machine to connect to sql server. This is something your DBA will have to do on your machine. execute the same executable again and select the `Management Tools` from `Features Selection` window, as shown in the below picture.

[image]